# Find the best fitting distribution using excel

Tags: excel, weibull, exponential-distribution

I estimated the theta of exponential distribution and the theta and tau of weibull distribution. I want to compare the two distribution to see which one is the best fitting of my data. How can i do that in excel? Can i find the R squared value in excel?

Comment: A larger R^2 value doesn't always mean a better model. With a polynomial of high enough degree you can make R^2  one, which doesn't prove that such models should be automatically adopted.

Comment: To expand on my previous comment -- exponential *is* Weibull with tau = 1, so *of course* you will get a better R^2 statistic with Weibull -- but there is a real danger of over-fitting the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use function correl(x range, y range) and make it square.

for example

```
=CORREL(A1:A10,B1:B10)^2
```

For more information go to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYcYyxoKq0U